A lower bound for finite integer sequence with $a_n > (a_{n-1} + a_{n+1})/2$
Question
Cristiano Ronaldo writes a sequence $a_1$, $a_2$$,...,$ $a_{100}$ of integers in which the first and last terms are equal to $0$. Except for the first and last terms, each term $a_i$ is larger than the average of its neighbours $a_{i−1}$ and $a_{i+1}$.
What is the smallest possible value for the term $a_{19}$
Initial findings
Since both ends of the series, i.e., $a_1, a_{100}$ are $0$, I have a feeling that the series is symmetrical.
The series increases gradually and peaks at the middle.
Also, I have observed that $a_n > \min ({a_{n-1}, {a_{n+1}}})$
I also have a feeling that the first fifty terms obey this formula, $a_n > \frac {n-1}{n}{a_{n+1}}$
And that's pretty much all I can come up with.
From https://gonitzoggo.com/problem/586

@MartinR Thanks for the advice. I have updated my question.

Care to explain the relevance of Cristiano Ronaldo in this question?

Let $N$ be a positive even integer and $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N$ be integers with $a_1 = a_N = 0$ and
$$
  a_n > \frac 12 (a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}) \text{ for } 2 \le n \le N-1 \, .
$$
Since all $a_n$ are integers, it follows that
$$
 a_{n+1} - 2a_n + a_{n-1} \le -1  \text{ for } 2 \le n \le N-1 \, .
$$
We can prove that
$$ \tag{*}
 \boxed{a_n \ge b_n := \frac 12 (n-1)(N-n) \text{ for } 1 \le n \le N \, .}
$$
First note that $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_N$ are integers with $b_1 = b_N = 0$ and
$$
 b_{n+1} - 2b_n + b_{n-1} = -1  \text{ for } 2 \le n \le N-1 \, .
$$
So if $(*)$ has been proven then that bound is sharp.
We define $c_n = a_n - b_n$ ($1 \le n \le N)$, then $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_N$ are integers with $c_1 = c_N = 0$ and
$$ \tag{**}
 c_{n+1} - 2c_n + c_{n-1} \le 0  \text{ for } 2 \le n \le N-1 \, .
$$
It remains to show that $c_n \ge 0$ for $2 \le n \le N-1$. That is true because $(c_n)_{n=1}^N$ is a “finite concave sequence” and therefore its minimum is the first or last element. More precisely: Assume that
$$
  m = \min \{ c_n \mid 1 \le n \le N \} < 0
$$
and let $j$ be the smallest index with $c_j = m$. We know that $j \ne 1$ and $j \ne N$, so
$$
 m = 2c_j \ge c_{j+1} + c_{j-1} \ge m + m = 2m \\
\implies c_{j+1} = c_{j-1} = m
$$
and that is a contradiction. This proves $(**)$ and therefore $(*)$.

@BenjaminWright: $a_n = \min(n, 100-n)$  satisfies the given condition, so $a_1 = 1$ is surely possible.

@BenjaminWright: I have rewritten the solution completely, hopefully it is correct now.

I think in your second inequality, in the term $a_{n+1}-2a_n+a_{n+1}$, one of the $a_{n+1}$'s should be replaced with $a_{n-1}$, and similarly for the other terms with $b_n$ and $c_n$

@EwanDelanoy: Yes of course, thanks! (I made the error once and copied it twice :)

@MartinR You are the truly the best. I cannot put my gratitude into words. The website accepted the final answer which was 729.
